# How to add decimal to int?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How can I add a decimal to an INT.
for example with the data below:

12452 into 124.52

500 into 5.00

1659865 into 16598.65

I have try this query but this is only for decimal :

```
select convert(decimal(10,2),sum(balance)) as Balance   
from member
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just divide by 100:

```
select convert(decimal(10,2),sum(balance)/100.0) as Balance   
from member
```

Converting doesn't change the actual value<sup>*</sup> - it just changes the data type, so `500 (int)` becomes `500.00 (decimal(10,2))`

<sup>*Unless the conversion itself changes the value due to a decrease in scale or precision (e.g. converting `1234.56` to `decimal(5,1)` would result in a value of `1234.6`)</sup>